# Problema a cargar un Listview vacio

Tags: android, listview

Tengo un `Listview` que funciona perfecto cuando tiene datos, pero al estar vació, es decir sin datos en la tabla de la BD, la aplicación de detiene. he validado que cuando no se encuentre conexión o ocurra alguna excepción muestre un mensaje, pero no entiendo por que deja de funcionar al momento de estar vacio el `Listview`

```
    public class AsyncRefrescar extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(EnviarPregunta.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tCargando preguntas...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            url = new URL("http://bdauditorio.esy.es/Verpregunta/mostrarpre.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {


            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");


            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();


            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }


                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(EnviarPregunta.this);
            alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
            alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no se han podido cargar las preguntas. Intentelo de nuevo.");
            alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            alertaDeError.create();
            alertaDeError.show();
        } else {
            //Existen Datos
            List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String>();

            //Parsea la respuesta obtenida por el Asynctask
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            assert jsonArray != null;
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject preguntaDatos = null;
                try {
                    preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String pregunta = null;
                try {
                    assert preguntaDatos != null;
                    pregunta = preguntaDatos.getString("pregunta");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                preguntas.add(pregunta);
            }

//crear el Adapter.
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EnviarPregunta.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
            //Asignas el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
            mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);




        }






    }

}

**unsuccessful** es cuando ha fallado la lectura hacia el servidor.
```

Comment: Que error te muestran los registros cuando se cierra la aplicación? Añade también tu Adapter y el código de tu Listview

Comment: @Keops  La app no se cierra, dice se ha detenido y vuelve al menu principal. He actualizado mi pregunta

Comment: Que error te muestran los registros?

Comment: @Maguz cuando la tabla de la base de datos contiene datos funciona todo bien, pero si borro los campos de la tabla es decir la dejo vacía se produce el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente no asignes los datos al Adapter si el ArrayList no contiene datos, puedes validarlo mediante el método `.isEmpty()`, este es un ejemplo de como podrías realizarlo:

```
   if(!preguntas.isEmpty()){ //Valida si preguntas no contiene datos!.
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EnviarPregunta.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
       //Asignas el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
       mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
```

---

Tu diseño es algo incorrecto, deberías recibir una respuesta en `onPostExecute()` y a partir de esta determinar si tiene o no datos, en base a esto llenar o no el  `Adapter`.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
```

Comment: Esto iría dentro del else no es así ?

Comment: si porque ahí asignas el Adapter que llenas con datos-

Comment: de usado el if(!preguntas.isEmpty()) y luego cargo el listview y un else que mustre un mensaje que no existen datos, pero me muestra este mensaje en ambos casos, este vacio o no el listview

Comment: he revisado todo lo que realizas, retornar strings con mensajes o un .json es un poco raro, revisa la actualización de mi respuesta.

Comment: Cual crees que seria la mejor manera?

Comment: onPostExecute() recibiría null o string vacio si no tuvo exito, si lo tuvo recibirá la respuesta json la cual tu parsearias y obtendrías los datos para el Adapter.

Comment: Sera necesario hacerlo de la manera que dices o lo que he hecho es una opción ? ya que hasta ahora ha cumplido la función de traer los datos de la BD al Listview

Comment: lo que has hecho es una opción pero en lugar de enviar un texto cuando ocurre un error, por ejemplo: return ("unsuccessful"); mejor realiza: return null; y dentro de onPostExecute() valida if(result != null) { entonces procede a parsear, si es null o no se tienen datos en la respuesta .json entonces muestra el díalogo =)

Comment: entiendo, gracias por la recomendación, marcare como positiva tu respuesta ya que es otra opción para que funcione ...

Answer (score 0):

Sin ver el log de errores, es fácil saber que ocurre.
Y es que **la forma en que usas los try-catch no tiene sentido**.

Solo usas catch para mostrar el error con `printStackTrace()`, pero por ejemplo, si tu variable no se define por algún error (o por el simple hecho de que tu BDD esta vacía) no deberías seguir avanzando, porque la variable necesita tener un valor asignado, y si continuas, esto ocasionará los errores que están ocurriendo.

Usa un try que envuelva todo el método y usa un catch(Exception e) o 2 o 3 Exception si conoces el tipo de error.

Ahora si tu BDD esta vacia, saldrá inmediatamente por el catch y tu error es más facil de controlar, y puedes cambiar el estado de la visibilidad a GONE del linearlayout que envuelve al listview

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {

        url = new URL("http://bdauditorio.esy.es/Verpregunta/mostrarpre.php");

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


            InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }


            return (result.toString());

        } else {

            return ("unsuccessful");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "exception";
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    pdLoading.dismiss();
    if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(EnviarPregunta.this);
        alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
        alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no se han podido cargar las preguntas. Intentelo de nuevo.");
        alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        alertaDeError.create();
        alertaDeError.show();
    } else {
        //Existen Datos
        List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Parsea la respuesta obtenida por el Asynctask
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject preguntaDatos = null;
                try {
                    preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String pregunta = null;
                try {
                    assert preguntaDatos != null;
                    pregunta = preguntaDatos.getString("pregunta");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                preguntas.add(pregunta);
            }

            //crear el Adapter.
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EnviarPregunta.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
            //Asignas el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
            mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(EnviarPregunta.this);
            alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
            alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no se han podido cargar las preguntas. Intentelo de nuevo.");
            alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            alertaDeError.create();
            alertaDeError.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Disculpa, tienes un ejemplo de esto ?

Comment: edite respuesta y solo junte los catch para que no avance

Comment: si tenias razón, ahora ha funcionado bien, gracias